# Upload image to server using Xcode 6 and PHP file

Tags: php, ios, xcode

I am trying to send image to my web site depending on user choice, every time the app should give the image's name which has been chosen by the user.

I am using Xcode 6 and the code below:

```
 NSString *urlString = @"http://MyWebSite.com/sendImages.php";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    // file
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image,90);
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"myImage.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:returnString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

And her is my PHP file:

```
<? 
    $myparam = $_FILES['userfile']; //getting image Here //getting textLabe Here 
    $target_path = "khadamati/";
    if(move_uploaded_file($myparam['tmp_name'], $target_path . basename( $myparam['name'])))

    { echo "The file ". basename( $myparam['name']). " has been uploaded"; } 

    else 

    { echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; } 

    ?>
```

How can I change the myImage name in this line:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"myImage.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I tried to find any thin that would help me, but I could not, so please find the mistake in my booth code.

Comment: You find your solution ? or any doubt ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this ,

uname,datestring ( i used here to define the user who has uploaded and the time when he uploaded  ).

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@receipt%@.jpg\"\r\n", uname,datestring]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

i hope it will be helpful to you , 
uname and datestring both are strings !